# How to perform groupy by with a user defined function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So i have two dataframes, one being a full dataset with many columns and each row being an observation.

The second dataframe is a subset of the first one, but counts the missing % of values in the column by a variable called "county."

so far i have a function that provides the intended results and provides the missing % for the overall column:

```
def missing_count(df, var):
    percent_missing= df[var].isnull().sum() * 100 / len(df)
    return round(percent_missing,2)
```

but what i want to do is make it specific to a county. e.g. - case number is 12% missing in county y, and 15% missing in county x. the code currently just says how many case numbers are missing in the entire dataframe. pretend there is 66 unique counties in the whole dataframe, i'm looking for 66 seperate missingness counts.

i'm trying to use groupby to get the result but it's not working.

```
df2['casenumber'] = df.groupby(by='county').apply(missing_count(df, 'casenumber'))
```

but this doesn't work and i get "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable".

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite your function so as it either takes a series, or a keyword variable `val`:

```
# series:
def missing_count(s, var):
    percent_missing= s.isnull().sum() * 100 / s
    return round(percent_missing,2)

df.groupby('county')['casenumber'].apply(missing_count)


# or keyword `val`
# careful for `KeyError`
def missing_count(d, var=None)
    percent_missing= df[var].isnull().sum() * 100 / len(df)
    return round(percent_missing,2)

df.groupby('county').apply(missing_count, var='casenumber')
```

That said, your code can be written as the following, which should be more performant:

```
df['case_number'].isnull().groupby(df['county']).mean()
```

Comment: hey thanks! that worked perfectly! i'm trying to create a function vs. using df['case_number'].isnull().groupby(df['county']).mean(), because the criteria for missingness gets a little more complex on other columns

Comment: @Nate, welcome to Stack Overflow! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)